# How can I view original branch of commits (and file changes) using git log?

Tags: git, logging, branch

I read a similar question about this that suggested using `git log --graph --all --decorate`.  The problem with this is that it doesn't display branch names for log entries that have had their branch merged and deleted long ago.

What I'm interested in is basically the exact same thing as the straight `git log` command, but with extra info to show me the name of the branch it was committed to and the files that were modified/added/deleted in the commit.  I'd like the branch name to be available regardless of whether or not it has been deleted.

Is there any way to do this without modifying the default commit message using a template or hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Andy answered - this info is not kept. If you will think about it it will become pretty clear that this information is not necessary at all. In git as in distributed VCS there is no point of knowing how another developer called his branch before the code got merged into the mainline. What is the point of knowing it? Does it really help? 
As for the other part of the question you can see the list of files changed between two points in history using

```
git whatchanged
```

or

```
git log --stat
```

Comment: I suppose the main reason I would want to know the branch name is that I often give short, two or three word descriptions of the work I was doing as the name of a branch.  So it would be nice to see it because I can quickly tell why those changes were committed.

As for the --stat switch, I should have read the man page more carefully but that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: if you really really need to know the branch name - you probably could look at the pre-commit hooks. You could put a script in place that will prefix all your new commit messages with the branch name you're currently having checked out. Then "git log [--one-line]" would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with git.  It doesn't keep track of the branch the commit was made to, so once you delete the branch, git has no idea that it ever existed.